# get path form google in json/xml/kml format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI....

How can i get route in the form of file or xml/kml/json format ??
Means I want to fond all the latitude and longitude between two location and i want to draw path on map.

path i can draw but i am not able to get all the latitude and longitude so can any body help me???

Answer (score 0):

Try appending "&output=kml" or "&output=json" to the end of your Google query URL.

Related Stackoverflow posts:
[Accessing Google Map Listing From GData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151741/accessing-google-map-listing-from-gdata)
[Search and display business locations on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640932/search-and-display-buisness-locations-on-mkmapview)