# Accessing Google Map Listing From GData

Tags: iphone, google-maps, gdata

Im trying to create a "search nearby" shops on iphone, 
but i can not find any solution on how to get the data from Gdata Libraries.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

They only support the following Google services provides a Google data API, but not google maps?!

Google Base
Blogger
Book Search
Calendar
Code Search
Contacts
Documents List
Finance
Health
Picasa Web Albums
Spreadsheets
Webmaster Tools
YouTube

Any solution or idea where i should look for would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to use the KML output format from a standard Google search:

`http://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=italian%20category:restaurants&sll=-37.816518,144.890628&sspn=0.007247,0.012424&ie=UTF8&z=12&output=kml`

Although you should check Google's terms and conditions to see if you're allowed to use that as an API.