# how to get a location at mkmapview with searchBar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, search, mkmapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search MKMapView with UISearchBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281798/how-to-search-mkmapview-with-uisearchbar)

okay now I have a MkMapView that show the currentLocation, but I want to make a search bar to make shortcut that will play a animation to target, such as.. I fill the searchBar with the name of some Street example "Independence Street" and mkmapview will make a current location move to the target. how can I do so? any code to make it easier?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", searchBar.text];
```

It gives the latitude and longitude

Comment: how can I make google map directly show my current location and my target location? any code arnold?

Comment: set an outlet to mapView.Then mapViewName.showUserLocation=YES;