# Searchbar suggestions with google maps in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-maps, mkmapview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to search MKMapView with UISearchBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281798/how-to-search-mkmapview-with-uisearchbar)

I have one UISearchBar with MKMapView with google maps. I need suggestions whenever i started typing. So what should i need to do for that ? Is there any web service for google api ?

Comment: Be careful about doing this on iOS 6. Google's API license states that you can only display its data on its maps. Since iOS 6 uses Apple's maps you can't use Google's API to get data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CLGeocoder` to generate address results based on a string. 

This is known as `forward geocoding`. 
You'll get a number of placemarks returned which you can populate into your UI.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html

Quick example here:

```
NSString *address = @"Big Ben";

CLGeocoder *coder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[coder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error){

     //Do something with the returned placemarks
}];
```

You can also restrict results to a set region if specific, that's all documented at the link above.

Comment: He is not asking about placemarks ! he is asking about suggestions. MKMapView is just part of UI. He is asking for general suggestions from google.

Comment: It sounded like he wanted location recommendations, based on the question (which this would produce).

Comment: Now, I also wonder - may be he is looking for just locations suggestions. Edited your answer & upvoted. My Apology

Answer (score 0):

1. create a request http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=YOURQUERY
2. receive response & parse it.
3. Display it into your UITableView as a suggestions.

To see complete illustration go [through this post](http://sugartin.info/2012/10/05/implementing-google-suggestions-into-your-ios-app/).