# How to add a UISearchBar in a map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add a `UISearchBar` on map for apple in iOS7. I've seen this question here [How to search MKMapView with UISearchBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281798/how-to-search-mkmapview-with-uisearchbar/2292587#2292587), but this code doesn't work in my project because there are several methods currently deprecated.

This is the code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *SearchBar;
@end

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar
    {
        [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:theSearchBar.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            //Error checking

            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            region.center.latitude = placemark.region.center.latitude;
            region.center.longitude = placemark.region.center.longitude;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;
            double radius = placemark.region.radius / 1000; // convert to km

            NSLog(@"[searchBarSearchButtonClicked] Radius is %f", radius);
            span.latitudeDelta = radius / 112.0;

            region.span = span;

            [theMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Explain us what is the problem? Only deprecated methods?

Comment: Deprecated methods and that when  I put in my search bar something,nothing happens

Comment: Is this the complete code? Where is the search bar?